# I can not change android cordova icon

Tags: android, xml, cordova, icons, config

I am trying to change my app icon in the config.xml file. I have read w3.org documents and, i supose, with this code must be enought.

```
<platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/icon/logo.png" /> 
</platform>
```

However i have this fail and it does not works:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'icon'. One of '{"http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets":allow-intent,
>   "http://  www.w3.org/ns/widgets":allow-navigation,
>   "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets":plugin,
>   "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets":preference, "http:// 
>   www.w3.org/ns/widgets":hook}' is expected.

So i try it like this way:

```
<platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <allow-intent href="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"/>
        <allow-navigation href="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"/>
        <icon src="res/icon.png" />
</platform>
```

And the error keep being.
This is my complete config.xml code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="tta.kirolapp.v1" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Kirol App v1</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the
        deviceready
        event.
    </description>
    <author email="thym-dev@eclipse.org" href="http://www.eclipse.org/thym">
        Eclipse.org - Thym
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <allow-intent href="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"/>
        <allow-navigation href="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"/>
        <icon src="res/icon.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <engine name="android" spec="6.1.0" />
    <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />


</widget>
```

Config xml file:
[image]

Comment: Try a jpg file instead of a png....

Comment: That is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like

```
    <platform name="android">
    <!--
        ldpi    : 36x36 px
        mdpi    : 48x48 px
        hdpi    : 72x72 px
        xhdpi   : 96x96 px
        xxhdpi  : 144x144 px
        xxxhdpi : 192x192 px
    -->
    <icon src="res/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/android/xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
</platform>
```

have a look at [Cordova Docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html#android) for more platforms and detailed information

Comment: Why Is not this enought?   <platform>
        <icon src="res/icon.png" />
    </platform>

Comment: android comes with different sizes so you need to provide your icon in sizes. have a look at [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: If i use these lines eclipse shows error "Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'icon'. One of '{"http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets":allow-intent, 
  "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets":allow-navigation, "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets":plugin, "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets":preference, 
  "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets":hook}' is expected.
 - cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'density' is not allowed to appear in element 'icon'."

Comment: It shouldn't. are you sure you are adding this lines in config.xml in cordova project ?